# What all things will affect in an iOS App, if it is changed to Unlisted app in the App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

We have an iOS application which is basically for an Organisation usage. So Apple suggests me to change my app type to unlisted app. But I need some clarification on the unlisted type app. Following are my questions:

1. Will it affect the current installed users?
2. Will the user receive new version release notification of my app?
3. Can they update new version without remembering app link?
4. Will the app link be same as current even if it is changed to unlisted?

Comment: It sounds like Apple are suggesting you release it as a [custom app](https://developer.apple.com/custom-apps/). This is an app that you make available to specific organisations through their Apple Business Manager. Those organisations are then responsible for distributing the app to their users, preferably via their MDM. They can distribute redemption codes. Users who install bia redemption codes will get updates. Users who install via an MDM will get updates based on the MDM policy. You will have to release the custom app with a new bundle id. Existing installs will not be updated

Comment: This question should be asked at Apple, Inc's developer's forums.

Comment: because the app is not available to the general public they suggest that you publish it though an enterprise account. this is not listed on the public app store and only people you invite can download the app. Existing users will need to download the app again after being invited. then they will receive update notifications and things, they wont receive them for the app they downloaded from the public app store, as you wont be publishing updates there

Comment: This is not an enterprise app. Enterprise apps are only available to employees of the enterprise app member. Custom apps are still distributed via App Store connect and reviewed by Apple and you use a regular developer program membership.  But you are right that it is only available to organisations you select and it is, effectively, a new app.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks, I didn't even know anything about custom apps, not heard of them, i though the op was getting mixed up. Thanks